# Changing the color of a specific character

Tags: c, colors, character

Is there any way to change the color in the console of a specific character?
I'm using code blocks and, for example, I want to change the color of all `@` to red and all `o` to yellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a different function to achieve this task. I am adding a code to show how it can be done in C.`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void output(char *s)
{
int i=0;
while(*(s+i) !='\0')
{
    if(*(s+i)=='@')
   {
   textcolor(RED);
    cprintf("%c",*(s+i));
   }
   else if(*(s+i) =='.')
   {
    textcolor(YELLOW);
    cprintf("%c",*(s+i));
   }
   else
   {
   textcolor(WHITE);
   cprintf("%c",*(s+i));
   }
   i++;
}
}
void main()
{
char S[]="@shvet.";
output(S);
getch();
}
```

Here is the image for the output console window.
[image: Output]

Note that I have used cprintf function instead of printf. This is because cprintf send formatted output to text window on screen and printf sends it to stdin.

Comment: If this solves your query.Mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: It's just..neither CodeBlocks or Microsoft Visual Studio recognize the textcolor function..

Comment: specifically if you want to do it in Code Block then follow the following link , it might be helpful [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574849/how-to-change-text-color-and-console-color-in-codeblocks)

Comment: Thanks! You, sir, are a life saver :))