# Start cmd with black background and black font

Tags: colors, cmd

Is there anyway to start cmd (from the run-dialog (windows+r)) with black background color and black font? I know that I can just change the colors when I'm inside of the cmd and then (e.g if I changed color 1 and 2 to black) just write "color 12", but that's not what I want, I want to start it somehow with black/black without any configuration in cmd.. Is this possible?

Comment: `cmd /?`. See `/T` option. But same restrictions as `color` command: foreground and background can't have the same color.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that /T thing, but as you said, it's not working... But propably there is in fact a way, as if you can manually change both to the same it should somehow be possible to start with the same as well...

Comment: at least not with `cmd` standard command set. Maybe powershell is able to to that. Also messing with the registry might be a possibilty. Might your qeustion be a [xy-problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?

Comment: Nope, starting a cmd with color black/black is all I want..

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, doing this in batch might niot be possible,
but you might be able to call a c/c++ programm which sets the console color for you (the last time i checked cmd.exe was really bad in reverting any changes to its system settings when exiting a process).

So, look at [How to change text color and console color in code::blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574849/how-to-change-text-color-and-console-color-in-codeblocks) , copy it into a .cpp file, compile it (this is where i usually add a rant about how windows comes without installed compilers) and call it right after launching your cmd!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to lay it down but it is impossible in CMD to get black on black without altering the registry, using additional software, or additional code. Powershell would probably be the best way to go with it. I am not as experienced in that area but i did find a helpful webpage [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406264.aspx).