# How to add conio in Codeblocks?

Tags: c, gcc, conio

I'm trying to build and run this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

main()
{
textcolor(RED); 
cprintf("Hello, World!");

getch();
return 0;
}
```

I use code blocks - gcc compiler.As GCC doesn't support conio.h , i'm getting a lot of errors.I want to add a library which is needed for running this kind of programs.
Being instructed by a blog I downloaded conio21 from this link:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/conio/
but I can't find the libconio.a there.Can you please explain how to add the library?

Comment: If the `conio` that you downloaded is in the project directory, you need to use quotation marks, not angle brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and extract `conio` library that you link in your question. Inside of it take **conio.c** and **conio2.h** to your project folder. Then include conio2.h to your source code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"conio2.h"

main()
{
    textcolor(RED); 
    cprintf("Hello, World!");

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I tested, it works.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to take conio.c and conio2.h to my project folder? I have been trying for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Functions like textcolor used to work in old compilers, you can't use them in new compilers like GNU GCC used by Code::Blocks.

To see how to change textcolor, this link might be able to help you:

[How to change text color and console color in code::blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574849/how-to-change-text-color-and-console-color-in-codeblocks)

Comment: c::b is not a compiler